# Create View table in DB2 with data from DB1 in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have Yii application (Yii ver 1.xx) where I need to connect 2 DBs. It obtains data from DB1 and write it to DB2.

Below is the connection that I have in my main.php

```
    'db'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'schemaCachingDuration'=>3600,
    ),

    'db2'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'schemaCachingDuration'=>3600,
    ),
```

Based on the data in 'db2', I need to write it to 'db'. Below is the way I write the query:

```
$view_tbl = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW db.tableName AS ';
$view_tbl .= 'SELECT cl.client_id, cl.name
                FROM clients cl
                LEFT OUTER JOIN client_tob cl_tob ON cl_tob.client_id = cl.client_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN job_orders jo ON cl.client_id = jo.client_id
                WHERE cl.status = 1
                GROUP BY cl.client_id
                ORDER BY cl.client_id DESC';                

$query = Yii::app()->db2->createCommand($view_tbl);     
$exec = $query->execute();
```

The queries work when I run it locally. However, when I try to run it on the server, it gives me this error:

> Error 500
>   CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE VIEW command denied to
>   user 'db'@'localhost' for table 'tableName'

whats wrong here? is the way that I called & connect the db is wrong?